# Why does python virtualenv is set at workspace level instead of project level?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

this has been bugging me lately and I don't have a definitive answer for this.

Why python virtualenv is set at workspace level instead of project level.

At one time one can work on multiple projects and it's good to have all the projects in the single workspace and each project can have its own virtualenv.

But what happens if you have more than one virtualenv in one workspace. You have to manually select which  virtualenv to use.

Comment: Thats not how VSCode works, a workspace is equal to a project.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment for a multi-root workspace in your multi-root workspace configuration, but the Python extension won't do it for you. It doesn't have any way to know that's what you mean as some people set different environment for different workspaces, so it takes the route of setting it per directory/workspace.